# Unescape the escape character in string before rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I want to display string enclosed with double quotes (e.g. "ABC") in text box. Currently it is not displaying since double quotes are being escaped. It is problem only with escaping the double quotes.

E.g.

```
public const string countryName = "\"ABC\"";

<input id="txtCountryName" type="text" value="<%= countryName %>" />
```

I want to avoid using regex or replace method to solve this.

Is there any method available in C# to solve this.

Comment: Perhaps you mean that you want to remove the double quotes when displaying them?

Answer (score 3):

You have to do this:

```
<input id="txtCountryName" type="text" value="<%= Server.HtmlEncode(countryName) %>" />
```

**Explanation**

The problem is that your final HTML is being rendered like that:

```
<input id="txtCountryName" type="text" value=""ABC"" />
```

You have to call `Server.HtmlEncode` to encode the `"` in HTML.

Answer (score 2):

No, actually, they **aren't** being escaped.

To escape them, or rather encode them into their HTML entities, use `HtmlEncode()`:

```
<input id="txtCountryName" type="text" value="<%=Server.HtmlEncode(countryName)%>" />
```

On ASP.NET 4 you can use [a different set of delimiters `<%: %>`](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx) for automatic escaping:

```
<input id="txtCountryName" type="text" value="<%:countryName%>" />
```

Comment: @Adrian: Well in ASP.NET it's also an alias of `HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode()`.

Comment: Right. But I totally posted that seconds before you did :)

Answer (score 1):

`<input>` is not a server control, so your example just performs string replacement. This yields a result of

```
<input id="txtCountryName" type="text" value=""ABC"" />
```

which does not show what you want.

An elegant solution is to use a server control instead and to make *ASP.NET set the property* instead of just doing string replacement in HTML. That way, ASP.NET takes care of the escaping issues.

Step 1: Make your input control a server control. You do that by adding `runat="server"`.

Step 2: Use data binding syntax (`<%# ... %>`).

```
<input id="txtCountryName" type="text" runat="server" value="<%# countryName %>" />
```

Step 3: Perform data binding in codebehind:

```
public const string countryName = "\"ABC\"";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DataBind();
}
```

Voilà, the text box shows `"ABC"`.